# Laravel 6 upgrade error - with dependency

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-6, laravel-upgrade

I changed in my composer "laravel/framework": "^6.0". I ran the command composer update and I get an error!
Check the image below please.

[image]

What should i do?
Remove the dependency and try to find a solution or how i can handle this??

I have try to contact and request update from the dependecy -> [link](https://github.com/ignited/laravel-omnipay) but no answers!

Please any any advice i will appreciate thanks!

Comment: Are you folowing the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#upgrade-6.0) to upgrade? PHP 7.2 Required... Update your laravel/framework dependency to ^6.0 in your composer.json file (this is what you already did)... Next, examine any 3rd party packages consumed by your application and verify you are using the proper version for Laravel 6 support.... Looks like that package doesn't have support for laravel 6.x https://github.com/ignited/laravel-omnipay/issues/52

Comment: Not saying that it doesn't work with Laravel6, but from that GitHub page you posted: "_Omnipay for Laravel 5 & Lumen_"

Comment: So if my packages don't support laravel 6.0 what should I do?  Try to find a other packages or solutions?

Comment: Yep, either that or don't upgrade to Laravel6. Or, if you can, fork the package and make adjustments for Laravel6 yourself

Comment: I had same issue before. As I remember, I created new projected and install all packages. Lastly moved my app, config, database, resources and routes folder there. Don't forget public & storage folder if you have data there.

Comment: How about creating a separate Laravel6 project, installing the library, and checking the version?

Comment: After think about all the suggestions i will 1º install laravel 6 and install again library's etc... thanks to all that have spend time helping =)